# Accessing a layout's TextView from an Activity with a different layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, navigation-drawer

I have a `mainActivity.java` class with a layout called `activity_main.xml` and a .xml file named `drawer_menu.xml` which has a `textView` that's displayed in the app's `drawer menu`.I want to set the drawer menu's `textView` text to a `String` value that i have in my `mainActivity.java` class. *How can i access that textView inside the mainActivity class?*

activity_main.java (the part accessing the textView):

```
    /**
 * Prompts the user for his/her username
 * when the tutorial is done
 */
private void promptForUsername() {
    UsernameDialog dialog = new UsernameDialog();
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"USERNAME_DIALOG");
    username.setText(getUsername());
}

public void setUsername(String name) {
    tempName = name;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return tempName;
}
```

UsernameDialog.java class:

```
public class UsernameDialog extends DialogFragment {

@BindView(R.id.editText) EditText mEditText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // inflate the layout using the dialog themed context
    final Context context = getActivity();
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.username_dialog,null,false);

    final MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();

    ButterKnife.bind(this,view);

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener posListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            activity.setUsername(mEditText.getText().toString());
            Log.d("USERNAME",mEditText.getText().toString());
        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle("Choose your username")
            .setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",posListener);
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

drawer_menu.xml (contains the TextView to be accessed):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:background="@color/NavigationDrawerHeader">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/menu_logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/user_icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/menu_logo"
    android:layout_marginStart="93dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/alegreya_sans_extrabold"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    android:text="username"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code at the end of `onCreate()` method in `MainActivity.java`

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
//R.id.nav_view the id of the navigation drawer

View drawerHead = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
//0 index of the header

TextView userName = drawerHead.findViewById(R.id.username);
```

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail see my edit to the answer I hope it helps tell me if it didn't we could figure out why

Comment: Sadly it still doesn't change anything :( . I changed some of my code so that the username is stored in the internal storage with SharedPrefs but the same thing keeps on happening

Comment: beside that my answer solves an error in your code I recommend see the below link to compare what is wrong with your code as I think that another thing is wrong but I can't see or not in this segment of code
http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2012/07/dialogfragment-with-interface-to-pass.html

Comment: From what i can tell this link is about passing data back and forth to an activity which is not a problem i have. My problem is accessing a textView that's on a different layout than that of the activity's

Comment: You don't need to pass the textview between pages but you can pass the data to the activity that have that textview and can change the text value

Comment: That "activity" is the drawerMenu and it doesn't have an activity.java file associated with it

Comment: I saw something right now `username.setText(getUsername());` this line need to be added to setUserName() function so after set text it will update the `textView`

Comment: Should be the same since if it's not set to the new text, the string already has a value of "error" but the issue is that it can't access it,hence the NPR

Comment: can u log the `username.getText()` value before and after `tempName = name;` line you will notice it doesn't change anything because show function on the dialog doesn't wait till the dialog dismiss to return and run the next line of code which change the value of the `username` `TextView` so you need to call `username.setText(getUsername());` inside `setUserName()`

Comment: I get that but since that doesn&#39;t happen the default value of &quot;error&quot; is set and logged but not displayed. I think you&#39;ve mixed some things up, the issue is that i am getting a NPE because I&#39;m trying to access the .setText method of a supposedly non existent  textView. I don&#39;t have any issues changing the String&#39;s value in code dynamically. The problem is accessing that textView without the NPE. What am i missing here? How should i approach accessing this view?

Comment: where do you inflate this drawerMenu.xml file ?

Comment: I have edited my answer again with I think the solution of your problem

Comment: that was it, i should have thought of that earlier. Good job and thanks for sticking with me on this one!

Answer (score 0):

you can define

```
    static TextView tv;
```

and can access to from other class

Comment: will i be able to change it's text dynamically though since it's static?

Comment: yes  just dont forget use it  tv=findviewbyid(r.id.urID);
if u dont use other class will be crash

Comment: same exact thing

Comment: can i get ur projcet ? and i will  fix it and i will send ur project 
i know what is problem class and xml related to this qeustion not total :)

Comment: Since you know what the problem is, why not post the answer here?I'm not sending you the project ;)

Comment: man i tell u this error :" null object refrence"
i know what is this icant fix it whiout sorce code

Comment: yeah i know that too, the thing is how can i avoid it? Your suggestion did not work. Do you have another one?

Comment: if you need like a whole class, then just ask for the class you dont need the project

Comment: u can edit question and put ur class and xml here if u dont trust me :)

Answer (score 0):

Nobody recommends the use of static views. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15614293/7910735) for more.

Now, for your situation you can create a String resource to be able use same text in both activities. How to do that? here:

- In your strings.xml add a string like this

> ```
> <string name="my_string">what ever u want to put here </string>
> ```

- Add TextView

> ```
>  TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Id_of_TextView);
>  textView.setText(getString(R.id.my_string));
> ```

**OR**

You can add that string directly in both textview's xml.

And to get the string value in a variable you can use

```
String temp = getResources().getString(R.string.my_string);
```

Comment: The problem is that the text changes dynamically so i can't use a String resource

Answer (score 0):

If you give the textview an id on the xml layout file, you could then use TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

Comment: I've tried this but it's causing the nullPointerException

Comment: are you using fragments?  if so, you might need to call this.getActivity() or if it's a textview in another layout you may need to inflate the layout first by using the layout inflator. (i'm guessing the names, but I think you see what I mean.)

Comment: i do actually, i just posted my code so take a look if you have some free time :D

Comment: I think Ahmed is right (see his Edit).  It seems like you should be calling this.getActivity(...) or something.  But my larger question is it seems this is a field that will remain for that user so it almost seems like you should be handling this as a User Preference for which there is a specific dialog fragment you can use.  if you did it that way once they close the dialog the user preference store would know the value for the username entered and you would have access to it to populate the textview.  google "android shared user store" and "anddroid user preferences fragment" examples.

Comment: that's what i wanted to do actually, is there an actual dialog for that?

Comment: I just saved it to the internal storage using SharedPrefs but still the problem keeps on happening. It throws the same NullPointerException.Isn't that because of the mainActivity trying to access an xml element from a different layout?